# Doctrine OrderBy a PHP Function

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity city that has an **address** attribute and a PHP function `calculate($addess)` that takes the city attribute address and returns a number.

I m trying to use the return of the function `calculate()` to order my cities. is it possible with Doctrine DQL? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance for any guidance

```
public function calculate($address)
{
    //... 
    return  $number;
}
```

I don't know if that exists but this is what I'm trying to do:

```
$qb
    ->select('u')
    ->from('City', 'u')
    ->orderBy(calculate($address), 'ASC')
;
```

Address needs to be a City attribute.

Comment: a bit of code would help

Comment: @t-n-y  a bit of could would help?

Comment: code, sorry, just edited it

Comment: @Achraf, Can you show your Code?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev  just edited it

Comment: @t-n-y just edited

Comment: $qb->select('u')
->from('City', 'u') in `Repository`?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev yes

Comment: do you see that this may be a soltuion http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html#registering-your-own-dql-functions

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what calculate() logic does but couldn't you give it to your class as parameter? Than add adress_number to yor DB and mapping and simply orderBy this parameter:

```
$qb->select('u')
    ->from('City', 'u')
    ->orderBy('u.adressNumber', 'ASC');
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: But what if the number corresponding to an addresse changes depending on the context? Let say the user requesting the list of City uses a certain type of transportation. Wheter is is currently using a bike or a car might change th "number" (ie sort order) of the cities, based, in this case, on a bike-friendly network of roads, for exemple.

Comment: it's not possible because caluclate function get the user location by geolocation and then return the distance between the user location and city .the user it's not same then the distance will not be the same. the order of the cities then will be differente form a user to another depanding of the user position. @DenisSt-Michel